# Delphi XE: TSQLQuery raises "Input parameter mismatch"

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, dbexpress, mismatch

I've created a stored procedure (`SP_TEST`) in Firebird 2.5 that returns a selection and uses 3 input parameters.
This `SP_TEST` works fine in IBExpress, when I enter e.g. the SQL command: `select * from SP_TEST(1,2,3)` there's a correct result.

However, when I use the dbExpress components in Delphi XE to do the same selection, the message "Input parameter mismatch" is raised.
I'm using the TSQLQuery component, with the CommandText property set to `"select * from SP_TEST(1,2,3)"`.
When I define the same query in the CommandText property as I've defined in `SP_TEST`, I have a nice result.
But including the stored procedure name in the select statement (with the right number of parameter) raises this error message.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE - moved from pseudo-answer** and formatting added: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_TEST (
    NJAAR Integer,
    NMAAND Integer,
    CREKNR Varchar(6) )
RETURNS (
    TOTAAL Numeric(15,2),
    CODE Varchar(4),
    OMSCHR Varchar(40),
    RICHTING Varchar(3),
    PROG Numeric(18,2),
    TRANS Numeric(18,2) )
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT a.CODE, a.OMSCHR, a.RICHTING,
    SUM(iif(richting='AF',-1,1) * COALESCE(p.bedrag,0)) as prog,
    SUM(iif(richting='AF',-1,1) * COALESCE(t.bedrag,0)) as trans,
    0 as totaal
    FROM POSTEN a
    left JOIN prognose p on p.POST = a.CODE and p.JAAR = :nJAAR and p.MAAND = :nMAAND
    left JOIN TRANSACT t on t.POST = a.CODE and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.datum) = :nJAAR and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.datum) = :nMAAND
    WHERE REKTOEPAS containing :cREKNR
    GROUP by a.CODE, a.OMSCHR, a.RICHTING
    INTO :CODE,
         :OMSCHR,
         :RICHTING,
         :PROG,
         :TRANS,
         :TOTAAL
  DO
  BEGIN
    totaal = iif(abs(prog) > abs(trans),prog,trans);
    SUSPEND;
  END
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Entering the statement in IBExpert:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_TEST(2014,1,'0001')
```

returns a result set of several rows.

When I pass the same query to `TSQLQuery.CommandText` (or to the `SQL` property, I also tried this), the message "Input parameter mismatch" is raised.

I tried `TSQLStoredProc`, but then there's a message "Cursor not returned from Query" when I use the Open method.

In fact, my stored procedure is kind of a view, and I like the result in my dbExpress components (`TSQLQuery` or `TSQLStoredProc`).
As said, when I put the complete SQL code between "SELECT..." and the "GROUP BY" in the `TSQLQuery.SQL` propery, I get the resulting rows.  Using the stored procedure fails until now.

Comment: I'm confused. You say that using the SQL command 'select * from PROC()` works, but the one using `select * from SP_TEST()` fails. They're two different statements (one uses `PROC()` and the other `SP_TEST()`). Can you [edit] to explain what the actual problem is you're having?

Comment: Would have expected execute sp_test(1,2,3) ...

Comment: http://SSCCE.org  Show the Code. Show the declaration of SP. Show how you arrange TSQLQuery, all the properties that you change and how do you open it -  everything. We cannot guess about things we cannot see. And show exact verbatim error text. Your query "select * from SP_TEST(1,2,3)" does not have parameters at all.

Comment: Use the `TSQLQuery.SQL` property instead of the `TSQLQuery.CommandText` property.  Or switch to `TSQLStoredProc`.

Comment: Can TSqlStoredProc read many rows from SP? @RemyLebeau

Comment: Yes, if the stored procedure returns a result set. Then you would use its `First()` and `Next()` methods to navigate the set. If the stored procedure returns multiple record sets, you can use the `NextRecordSet()` method to access the extra sets.

Comment: This is the stored procedure:

Comment: I don't think "Input parameter mismatch" is the WHOLE text. at very least it lacks the class name of error. Please, copy the whole error window text

Comment: Is this "When I pass the same query to TSQLQuery.CommandText" using a vanilla TSQLQuery component created just in prior line ? Because that query does not have any parameters thus it looks like they are left from previous commands and you did something poor so not to remove no more used parameters. Also what is http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.CommandType ?

Answer (score 0):

Your third parameter is a `VARCHAR`, but you try to use `select * from SP_TEST(1,2,3)` and here the third argument is an `INTEGER`. This is also the only difference with the procedure call that does work.

So instead use:

```
select * from SP_TEST(1,2,'3')
```

(note the quotes around the 3)

Comment: Sorry, the first parameter list was a quick example, the last example is the real parameter list for the SP I listed:  SELECT * FROM SP_TEST(2014,1,'0001')